# Issue Linking to Google Play in Firebase App Distribution

Tags: firebase-app-distribution

I'm attempting to distribute an Android app bundle via Firebase App Distribution. I'm following the docs here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6392038?authuser=1

I seem to be getting stuck on the "How to Link" section, however, as the Google Play Integration card is telling me "Required Permissions Missing".

[image]

I believe I meet the prerequisites to link:

- I am logged in as an Owner in both Firebase and Google Play.
- The app is registered with both Firebase and my Google Play developer account.
- The app in Google Play and Firebase share the same package name.
- The app is published in Production in the Play Store.

Not sure what else is required, or if I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have same problem, did you find the solution?

Comment: Hey, did you find the problem? I'm facing the same issue, but, not sure what I need to do yet. I managed to assign admin roles to me, like Marcelo's answer, but the problem is not solved yet.

Comment: Same problem here. My account is owner AND firebase administrator, but is always "Required Permissions Missing". I've not idea what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Give your gmail account to admin which one using google play developer account. must be same google developer account gmail and firebase account's gmail.

Answer (score -1):

Despite being the project's owner, firebase won't allow you to link it to google play. You have to give yourself an administrator role by going under users and permissions tab and click in your user's role. Next you can assign yourself as administrator. There you go, now you can link your project to google play.